Edge-weighted Spring Embedded Layout based on identity in py4cytoscape
I am trying to automate the creation of networks using Cytoscape. Specifically, I want to use the Edge-weighted Spring Embedded Layout based on identity with py4cytoscape. While this layout is available manually in Cytoscape (Layout > Edge-weighted Spring Embedded Layout > identity), I have been unable to find a script to implement it programmatically.
I am providing Cytoscape with a GML file containing all the necessary information. The structure of the GML file is as follows:

graph [
  node [
    id 0
    label "labelname1"
  ]
  node [
    id 1
    label "labelname2"
  ]
  node [
    id 2
    label "labelname3"
  ]
  ...
  node [
    id 2125
    label "labelnamex"
  ]
  edge [
    source 0
    target 0
    identity 100.0
  ]
  edge [
    source 0
    target 1
    identity 44.4
  ]
  edge [
    source 0
    target 2
    identity 32.9
  ]
  ...
]

Here are the possible layouts available in Cytoscape:
['attribute-circle', 'stacked-node-layout', 'attribute-grid', 'degree-circle', 'circular', 'attributes-layout', 'kamada-kawai', 'force-directed', 'cose', 'grid', 'hierarchical', 'fruchterman-rheingold', 'isom', 'force-directed-cl'] 

Each layout has different properties, which can be retrieved using the command:
p4c.get_layout_property_names('...') 

For example:
p4c.get_layout_property_names('kamada-kawai')

['m_averageIterationsPerNode',
 'm_nodeDistanceStrengthConstant',
 'm_nodeDistanceRestLengthConstant',
 'm_disconnectedNodeDistanceSpringStrength',
 'm_disconnectedNodeDistanceSpringRestLength',
 'm_anticollisionSpringStrength',
 'm_layoutPass',
 'singlePartition',
 'unweighted',
 'randomize']

or
p4c.get_layout_property_names('force-directed')

['numIterations',
 'defaultSpringCoefficient',
 'defaultSpringLength',
 'defaultNodeMass',
 'isDeterministic',
 'singlePartition']

Could you help me find or create a script that applies the Edge-weighted Spring Embedded Layout based on identity using py4cytoscape or py2cytoscape?

Edge-weighted spring-embedded is Kamada-Kawai, so that's the one you should use.  In order to you do an edge weighting, though, you need to first create the network, then create an edge column with your edge attributes, then you should see the parameter to provide the column.  Note that the column must be a numeric column, though.
